# A better way to store image with discord py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am developing a discord bot and some commands require the user to input a file. The problem comes when fetching the files since as for now, I am using the URL. But with discord new update, any discord link older than a certain amount of minute won't display the image anymore.

For context I simply use the image in an embed I send and I use sqlite3 to store all the information the user input.

The question is how to store the image with two constraints:

1. It has to be efficient
2. It has to be safe (avoid any malwares)

Comment: From what I've read, it seems like the change only affects links outside of Discord. But with the wording of the message, we still need to wait for more information and confirmation from Discord about this change.